# Mapbox source using TileJSON causing problems on iOS

Tags: ios, mapbox, tile

so I have a problem trying to display a map from an internet source with Mapbox using TileJSON.
I have no problem using a local .mbtiles file or creating an online map using a map ID, but whenever I try to use TileJSON to prevent errors when I don't have network access, I can't seem to load any tile (the map zooming and other gestures are still working though, I can see my annotations and user position).

Here's the code I use to (try) display OpenCycleMaps.

```
RMMapboxSource *lOnlineTileSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithTileJSON: @"{\"tiles\": [ \"http://a.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png\" ], \"minzoom\": 0, \"maxzoom\": 18}"];

[lOnlineTileSource setCacheable:YES];

self.mMapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame andTilesource:lOnlineTileSource];
```

Also, I can see this being logged when I attempt to create a map from the internet with TileJSON:

```
DB Error: 1 "near "-": syntax error"
DB Query: PRAGMA cache-size=100
DB Path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A3B998A1-E617-420F-9FBD-1D8396034005/Documents/RMTileCache.db
```

If you could help me figure out what I am doing wrong here, that'd be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax error of FMDB

find

```
executeQuery:@"PRAGMA cache-size=100"
```

change to

```
executeQuery:@"PRAGMA cache_size=100"
```